# Query MS graph API to get all sites containing 'ABC' in URL through Power Automate

Tags: search, power-automate, microsoft-graph

I have been trying to work out this using `Power Automate` to list all sites in the site collection with the URL that contains at the end "ABC". I don't want to use names as it's not consistent.

I have tried using this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=ABC$top=2"
```

But it doesn't return the right result. The documentation states query but what are the query options.

So if a site is `https://tenant.sharepoint/sites/ABC` or `https://tenant.sharepoint/sites/ABCD`.

I want to filter sites that are like 'ABC' or contains 'ABC'.

Also the [Get a site resource by path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-getbypath?view=graph-rest-1.0) doesn't explain much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You may have to filter the result set that comes back to remove some extraneous results, but it should get you the results you're looking for.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?$search="ABC"
```

For more information on the use of `$search` in Microsoft Graph see: [Use the search query parameter to match a search criterion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-query-parameter)

Comment: Thanks Rob and thats what exactly i was doing.

Comment: @naijacoder Sorry for missing that my suggestion was to do exactly what you were already doing. I guess I was focused on the answer more than I was on the question. ‍♂️